# Replacing disposable object registered as singleton in Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, autofac

I am creating a library that contains a class `MyService`  that uses a 3rd party object `DisposableDbObject` (implementing `IDisposable`). I expose Autofac `ContainerBuilder` extension that registers it as a single instance (creation of object is very costly). The thing  is that once in a while the `DisposableDbObject` instance needs to be refreshed (it's a wrapper around some in-memory DB that needs to load a new version of database from file). Since, as far as I know, there is no safe way to replace the reference of a component of `SingletonInstance` (and `ContainerBuilder.Update` is obsolete) I wrapped my `DisposableDbObject` with `DisposableDbObjectProvider` class and register it as a singleton, while having a free hand to update whatever lies underneath. So my setup goes like this.

```
// DisposableDbObjectProvider.cs
public interface IDisposableDbObjectProvider  
{
    DisposableDbObject GetDb();
}

public class DisposableDbObjectProvider : IDisposableDbObjectProvider  
{
    private DisposableDbObject _obj;
    public DisposableDbObjectProvider() 
    {
        _obj = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\file");
    }
    public DisposableDbObject GetDb()
    {
         return _obj;
    }
    public void UpdateDb() 
    {
        _obj = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\new\file");
    }
}

// MyService.cs 
interface IMyService 
{
    string GetStuffFromDb();
}

class MyService 
{
    private DisposableDbObjectProvider _provider;

    class MyService(IDisposableDbObjectProvider provider) 
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    public string GetStuffFromDb() 
    {
        return _provider.GetDb().Read(...);
    }
}


// AutofacExtensions.cs
static class AutofacExtensions 
{
     public static ContainerBuilder WithMyService(this ContainerBuilder builder) 
     {
          builder.RegisterType<DisposableDbObjectProvider >().As<IDisposableDbObjectProvider>().SingleInstance();
          builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>();
     }
}
```

Now there are at least three problems with this setup.

1. The multithreaded client app (like ASP.NET WebApi2) registers `MyService` and one one thread (be it ASP.NET request handler) it can access two different versions of the object if the update was performed while thread is running (in my very specific case this might be good enough, event though I would prefer to avoid that)
2. After replacing `DisposableDbObject` reference, the old one needs to have `Dispose` called upon it. Now there might be N >= 1 threads that keeps reference to that object, and while I call `Dispose` in `DisposableDbObjectProvider` those thread may (and in many cases will) end up with `ObjectDisposedException`.
3. It breaks the rule that the client should be responsible for disposing the object it uses.

One approach I was thinking about is to change registration of `DisposableDbObjectProvider` to transient with `DisposableDbObject` as `static` field and on each update save the old reference as `WeakReference` tracking list and scan it for references that are garbage collected (via `IsAlive` property) and call `Dispose` on those, like below

```
public class DisposableDbObjectProvider : IDisposableDbObjectProvider, IDisposable 
{
    private static DisposableDbObject _obj  = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\file");
    private static List<WeakReference> _oldRefs;
    public DisposableDbObject GetDb()
    {
         return _obj;
    }
    public void UpdateDb() 
    {
         _oldRefs.Add(_obj);
         _obj = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\new\file");
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        var deadRefs = _oldRefs.Where(x => !x.IsAlive);
        oldRefs = oldRefs.Exclude(deadRefs);
        foreach(var deadRef in deadRefs) 
        {
            ((IDisposable) deadRef.Target).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But that just might solve problem no 2 and still I don't feel very safe about this soultion (can't tell if `DisposableDbObjectProvider.Dispose` will behave as intended while called simultaneously by several threads.

What would be the best way to overcome these issues? Of course my solution to bypassing the singleton registration problem might be flawed, if there is a better approach I'm eager to hear about it.

Comment: How do you/does the program decide when to refresh the DisposableDbObject? If there is a pattern, you could stop registering it as a singleton and pass the correct (number of) instances around.

Comment: Please show us the source code for `DisposableDbObject`. _Seeing it may open up opportunities that aren't obvious otherwise._

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would say I am missing thread safety. If object is in use it cannot be updated until all other threads are done with the work. Same for update routine. Before it is done other threads should not be able to access object or its methods. It is not trivial and I will avoid trying to implement such a thing without deep understanding. Good news is there is a [ReaderWriterLockSlim class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) that is designed to allow multiple threads to read, but just a single thread to write at a time. It will also let you dispose existing object as during the write no read lock is acquired and vice versa.

```
public class DisposableDbObjectProvider : IDisposableDbObjectProvider, IDisposable 
{
    private DisposableDbObject _obj  = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\file");
    private ReaderWriteLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);

    public DisposableDbObject AquireDb()
    {
         if(_lock.TryEnterReaderLock(100)) // how long to wait until entering fails
         {
             return _obj;
         }
         else
         {
            // unable to enter read lock in timeout
            // do something
         }
    }

    public void ReleaseDb()
    {
         // we need to exit lock after we are done with reading
         _lock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    public void UpdateDb() 
    {
         if(_lock.TryEnterWriteLock(500)) // how long to wait until entering fails
         {
            _obj.Dispose();
            _obj = new DisposableDbObject("D:\\path\to\new\file");
            _lock.ExitWriteLock(); // We need to leave write lock to let read lock to be acquired
         }
         else
         {
             // unable to enter write lock in timeout
             // do something
         }
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        _obj.Dispose();
    }
}
```

It may work for you, but probably you'll need to do some tweaks along the way, but the idea is hopefully clear and helpful.